infinite spring- jms test
I trying to write test for my springJmsListner, but it endlessly.I think its related with Context Caching but i'm not sure. I am using testContainers

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var jmsTemplate: JmsTemplate

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var jackson: ObjectMapper

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var jdbcTemplate: JdbcTemplate

    @Test
    fun testJmsListner() {

        val message = "message"
        val queue = "queue"


        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(queue, message)

        val sentMessage: Message? = jmsTemplate.receive(queue)
        if (sentMessage != null) {
            assertTrue(sentMessage::class.java.isInstance(TextMessage::class.java))
        }

        assertEquals(message, (sentMessage as TextMessage).text)

in logs i see that last operation in another thread,but i dont know how fit this
2024-05-06T16:22:58.646+03:00  INFO 10455 --- [tasks] [    Test worker] .j.a.l.p.testJmsListner : Started testJmsListner in 1.746 seconds (process running for 6.678)
2024-05-06T16:22:58.909+03:00  INFO 10455 --- [tasks] [ntContainer#0-1] some logs about my message is recieved

What happens? Does execution pass the receive(..) or blocks on that statement?

it pass on receive(..)
when i debugging on this point i get Skipped breakpoint at com.jms.Desereliaze because of stepping in another thread

My problem was in @JmsListener in project,it catch message and "recieve(..)" in test cant get already readed message.I am trying to do test, which check that my message will be correctly deserialize

You qualified what you really want in the comment above

I am trying to do test, which check that my message will be correctly deserialize

Depending on which JMS library is being used the message conversion may be handled in different ways.  So you could use a different call to get access to the Message before it gets sent.
Notice that convertAndSend(destination, message) has an alternative convertAndSend(destination, message, messagePostProcessor)
You could call that in your test and in the callback you'll get access to the converted Message
